# ruby on rails does update_attributes protect against sql injection?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Does update_attributes protect against sql injection?

Example:

```
 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     # updated
 end
```

I know find(), and {} and [] do in find :conditions, but didn't see any info on this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. Internally, it simply loops over all attributes, set their values then invoke save!

```
def update_attributes(attributes)
  with_transaction_returning_status do
    self.attributes = attributes
    save
  end
end

def attributes=(new_attributes, guard_protected_attributes = true)
  ...
  attributes.each do |k, v|
    if k.include?("(")
      multi_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
    elsif respond_to?("#{k}=")
      send("#{k}=", v)
    else
      raise(UnknownAttributeError, "unknown attribute: #{k}")
    end
  end
end
```

In other words, what it does is

```
m.update_attributes(:attr1 => "foo", :attr2 => "bar")

m.attr1 = "foo"
m.attr2 = "bar"
m.save
```

Answer (score 2):

All activerecord methods in Rails3 that interact with the database are safe from sql injection.

The only exception is if you use raw SQL for one of the options, for example:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => "user_id = #{params[:user]}")
```

the preferred form is:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => params[:user})
```

which will be automatically protected against SQL injection.